# Image not showing up on ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an image in a folder, when I try to set the `ImageUrl` from the behind code I get a little symbol that looks broken in half instead of the picture. If I set the `ImageUrl` in the Image properties it works. What am I doing wrong?

```
var imagepath = Server.MapPath(@"~/images/candidates/small/image.jpg");
System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(imagepath);
int ActualWidth = image.Width;
int ActualHeight = image.Height;
candImage.ImageUrl = imagepath;
candImage.Height = ActualHeight;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ImageUrl` should be the URL to the image, as you would get it from a browser, not its location on the hard drive, which is what `Server.MapPath` returns.

You should be using:

```
candImage.ImageUrl = @"~/images/candidates/small/image.jpg";
```

Comment: @user1599813 - That wasn't the purpose of the answer.